# Double linked list with multiple next node

Tags: java, xml, doubly-linked-list

I am having an xml with set of tasks, with each task consist of next and previous task ids. Based on xml data i need to load all task on as Double Linked List memory and then need to execute the DLL. Following is the sample xml.

```
<task id="1"> 
    <name>start</name>
    <task-class>dk.framework.task.StartTask</task-class>
    <task-type>start-task</task-type>
    <previous-task>0</previous-task>
    <next-task>2</next-task>
</task>
<task id="2"> 
    <name>validation</name>
    <task-class>dk.framework.task.UserValidationTask</task-class>
    <task-type>java-task</task-type>
    <previous-task>1</previous-task>
    <next-task>3</next-task>

</task>
<task id="3"> 
    <name>isSuccess</name>
    <task-class>dk.framework.task.BasicCondition</task-class>
    <task-type>condition-task</task-type>
    <previous-task>2</previous-task>
    <conditions>
        <condition response="TRUE">
            <next-task>5</next-task>
        </condition>
    <conditions>
    <conditions>
        <condition response="FALSE">
            <next-task>4</next-task>            
        </condition>
    <conditions>

</task>

<task id="4"> 
    <name>RetunErrorMessafe</name>
    <task-class>dk.framework.task.ErrorMessage</task-class>
    <task-type>message-task</task-type>
    <previous-task>3</previous-task>
    <next-task>7</next-task>
</task>
<task id="5"> 
    <name>InsertAudit</name>
    <task-class>dk.framework.task.InsertAudit</task-class>
    <task-type>java-task</task-type>
    <previous-task>3</previous-task>
    <next-task>6</next-task>
</task>
```

I can able to load these task into a Double Linked List based on the next-task and previous-task, but for task id "3" i have to make next node as both 4 and 5 based on condition. Can any one help on this issue?

Comment: If a task can have more than successor task then no you can't use a list. In a list every element can have at most one element before and one after it. You will need to use a tree structure. What exactly are for asking for? How to parse the XML, or what data structure to put your result in?

Comment: Data Structure to maintain xml data...

Comment: OK, if all your tasks have no more than 1 next task you can use a doubly linked list.

Comment: What you have here is a graph, where the nodes are tasks, and the edges are the next/previous relations.

Comment: @alexraasch Task3 has Task4 and Task5 as possible next.

Comment: @Ingo: Yes, I understand that. But I'm still confused about what exactly the OP is asking about.

Comment: @alexraasch: I just looking for best data structure to load my xml parsed data into memory and later execute it....

Comment: @Vinesh How can we know this? We don't know what it means to "execute it". But if you have a Task class, you could use an array (or ArrayList)

Answer (score 0):

The problem by itself is not a list by definition, an ordered collection. It "should" be a DAG (digraph acyclic graph) and if you have a cyclic, you will have problems. Normally, any transversing algorithm could be applied to find the list (of executable tasks) from this DAG problem and probably it is what you want. However, sometimes it could be more complicated. There is a whole branch of IA concern about action sequencing (planning and schedulling).